# I have two lists, I compared their values & when I append them into a new list, its repeating, I don't want repeat only union them. Please see below

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

List-1:

```
lst1 =
[{'key': 'data_collected.service_data'}, {'key': 'gdpr.gdpr_compliance'}, {'key': 'disclosure_of_information.purpose_of_disclosure'}, {'key': 'opt_out.choice_of_opt_out'}]
```

List-2:

```
lst2 = 
[{'key': 'child_data_protection.parent_guardian_consent'}, {'key': 'ccpa.ccpa_compliance'}, {'key': 'disclosure_of_information.purpose_of_disclosure'}, {'key': 'opt_out.choice_of_opt_out'}]
```

When i run this script:

```
res = []
for x in lst1:
    for y in lst2:
        if x["key"] == y["key"]:
            if x not in res and y not in res:
                res.append({"key": x["key"], "confidence": 1})
        else:
            if x not in res and y not in res:
                res.append(x)
                res.append(y)
print(res)
```

i am not getting proper output, OUTPUT should be like:

```
[{'key': 'data_collected.service_data'}, {'key': 'gdpr.gdpr_compliance'}, {'key': 'disclosure_of_information.purpose_of_disclosure', 'confidence': 1}, {'key': 'opt_out.choice_of_opt_out', 'confidence': 1}, {'key': 'child_data_protection.parent_guardian_consent'}, {'key': 'ccpa.ccpa_compliance'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your lists, you have defined dictionaries, which can only hold {key:value} format. A key cannot have multiple values, although you have tried to assign multiple values to a single key.
What you can do is set a list as your value for a particular key, and the list can contain multiple elements.

This is how I'd implement it:

```
lst1 = [{'key': 'data_collected.service_data'}, {'key': 'gdpr.gdpr_compliance'}, {'key': 'disclosure_of_information.purpose_of_disclosure'}, {'key': 'opt_out.choice_of_opt_out'}]
lst2 = [{'key': 'child_data_protection.parent_guardian_consent'}, {'key': 'ccpa.ccpa_compliance'}, {'key': 'disclosure_of_information.purpose_of_disclosure'}, {'key': 'opt_out.choice_of_opt_out'}]
res=lst1
for x in lst2:
    if x in res:
        res[res.index(x)].update({'key':[x['key'],{'confidence':1}]})
    else:
        res.append(x)       
print(res)
```